# svg text - rtl issue

Tags: svg, text

Whene i`m adding letter-spacing or word-spacing chrome flips rtl to ltr, and the letters\words are reversed.
here is a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/f57mc?file=/src/App.js

```html
<svg textAnchor="middle">
  <text x="50" y="50" direction="rtl" writing-mode="rl"
    letterSpacing="4">שלום</text>
</svg>
```

thank in advance for any help

Comment: Report Chrome bugs to [Chrome's bugtracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) but do search to see whether it's already been reported.

Comment: i've removed the "register-transfer-level" tag as does not relate to your question.

Comment: It is the same result in Firefox. Could it be something else then a bug?

Comment: @chrwahl Firefox looks correct to me (91.0.1 on Win10).

Comment: Apparently it happens the same when setting the textLength of the text - another way to add letter spacing in svg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

This is a known bug in the Chrome SVG renderer. The [Chrome bug number is 973581](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=973581).

See that bug report for more information.

---

*Old answer*

It's a definite bug.  I think it's just a deficiency in the text shaping algorithm of Chrome. The bug doesn't seem to affect the HTML text shaping code (see below).

Please report the bug, as others have said.  If you do, please add the bug number/link to this question for future reference.

```html
<svg>
  <text
    x="0"
    y="50"
    letter-spacing="4"
    >שלום</text>
</svg>

<p style="letter-spacing: 4px">שלום</p>
```

Comment: open a bug report  on Chrome's bugtracker
Issue number is: 1242970